# TypeError: this.props is not a function (react router / switch)

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've got a switch in App.js to render different body components. "Landing" is the landing page body component. It's got a text field to enter a zip code, and when you click the submit button, it renders the "Events" page body component that displays some stuff.

When the Events component loads, I need it to be able to access the zip code that the user entered on the Landing page, so I lifted "zip" to App.js, which is the parent of Landing and Events.

I'm using Route and Switch so I can render the different body components. It's not getting that far though:

> TypeError: this.props.onZipChange is not a function

No clue why it doesn't recognize onZipChange as a function in App.js. I won't bother showing the Events.js file because it's not even being rendered before I get the TypeError. The second I try to type into the input box in Landing.js, it triggers the input box's onChange attr, which calls this.handleChangeZip, which tries to call App.js' onZipChange function through this.props, which it's not recognizing.

Any thoughts?

App.js:

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from "react";
import "./styles/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./styles/App.css";
import "./index.css";
import Header from "./routes/Header";
import Body from "./routes/Body";
import { Switch, Route, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import Landing from "./routes/Landing";
import Events from "./routes/Events";
import Help from "./routes/Help";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { zip: "" };
    this.handleZipChange = this.handleZipChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleZipChange = newZip => {
    this.setState({ zip: newZip });
  };

  render() {
    const currZip = this.state.zip;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header zip={currZip} />
        <Switch>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/"
            render={props => <Landing {...props} zip={currZip} />}
            onZipChange={this.handleZipChange}
          />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/Events"
            render={props => <Events {...props} zip={currZip} />}
            onZipChange={this.handleZipChange}
          />
          <Route exact path="/Help" component={Help}></Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Landing.js:

```
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import React from "react";
import "../styles/App.css";

class Landing extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: "", toEvents: false };

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeZip = this.handleChangeZip.bind(this);
  }

  handleChangeZip(e) {
    this.props.onZipChange(e.target.value);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    this.setState(() => ({
      toEvents: true
    }));
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.toEvents === true) {
      return <Redirect to="/Events" />;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="main-body">
          <div className="main-question" id="thisfontonly">
            What city are you looking for?
          </div>
          <div className="textbar-and-button">
            <input
              onChange={this.handleChangeZip}
              value={this.props.zip}
              type="text"
              name="city"
              id="citylabel"
              style={{ fontSize: "24pt" }}
              className="rcorners"
            />
            <div className="buttons">
              <input
                onClick={this.handleSubmit}
                type="submit"
                name="submit"
                value="Go!"
                id="submit"
                className="button"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Landing;
```

Comment: Shouldn't you put `onZipChange={this.handleZipChange}` in the component props instead of the route props? `render={props => <Landing {...props} zip={currZip} onZipChange={this.handleZipChange} />}`

Comment: yeah @EmileBergeron's right

Comment: Yeah. Yep. You're 1000% right. I've been writing code for so long that my eyes are buggy. Thank you very much